# default pdf-reader changed from Evince to Gimp

Tags: pdf, gimp, default, evince

I am running 14.04 with all recent updates,  recently my default pdf-reader unexpectedly changed from Evince to Gimp.  My `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` points to `/etc/gnome/defaults.list` which says: `"application/pdf=evince.desktop"`  Gimp is used only once in my `defaults.list`, where it says `"image/x-psd=gimp.desktop"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click a pdf file and select `properties`. In the third tab "Open With" select the application you want pdf files to open with. At the bottom right corner, click `Set as default`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using (older) applications using `/etc/mailcap`, you might want to add the line

```
application/pdf; evince %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"
```

into `/etc/mailcap` between the "User Section Begins" and "User Section Ends" lines to fix it, or create an appropriate file into `/usr/lib/mime/packages`; see [Promote evince in /etc/mailcap.order](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118437/promote-evince-in-etc-mailcap-order).