# Promote evince in /etc/mailcap.order

Tags: evince, mime-type

GIMP very unexpectedly took over opening PDF files a while ago when issuing the `see` command. It is listed in `/etc/mailcap` before the more appropriate evince. Of course I can edit this file by hand, but since it is managed by the system, the next `update-mime` run will overwrite these changes.

There is a file called `/etc/mailcap.order` that promises to help to achieve exactly what I want. I added and entry there:

```
evince:application/pdf
```

However, the next `update-mime` run answers with:

```
Warning: package evince listed in /etc/mailcap.order does \
    not have mailcap entries.
```

Changing the package name to `evince-common` or changing the media type to `*/*` did not achieve anything. So what is the right format?

Comment: Did you create an entry for `evince` in `/usr/lib/mime/packages`? According to `man mailcap.order`, that is where `update-mime` looks.

Comment: Or maybe you can just remove the `gimp` entry there.

Comment: I missed that bit… However, in `/usr/lib/mime/packages` there are entries for neither gimp nor evince. Adding a file there seems just as bad as editing `/etc/mailcap` itself.

Comment: You can add the line between the "User Section Begins" and "User Section Ends" lines in /etc/mailcap. These lines should not be overwritten.

Comment: The lines seem to come from /usr/share/applications/*.desktop, where * matches, in particular, gimp (and google-chrome) before org.gnome.Evince.desktop. 
I cannot find an exact reference, but it looks like update-mime first processes files /usr/lib/mime/packages/* (in an order which is governed by 1) /etc/mailcap.order (see man mailcap.order) and 2) the alphabetical order of the files) and then /usr/share/applications/*.desktop, again in an alphabetical order of the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just following @Jos suggestion, I fixed this annoying issue with:

```bsh
echo 'application/pdf; evince %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY"' | sudo tee /usr/lib/mime/packages/evince
echo 'evince:application/pdf'| sudo tee -a /etc/mailcap.order 
sudo update-mime
```

Comment: I still believe it’s wrong from Ubuntu’s side. But this is a working work-around.

Comment: It looks like the second line is, in fact, not needed: update-mime seems to process files in /usr/lib/mime/packages before those in /usr/share/applications/*.desktop. The latter is where it gathers the information for Gimp and Evince from. (See the "desktop entries" section towards the end of the update-mime manpage.)

Answer (score 1):

You can add the line between the "User Section Begins" and "User Section Ends" lines in /etc/mailcap. These lines should not be overwritten by `update-mime`.

However, at least if you are managing more computers through some deployment system, the solution by fuujuhi may be better.